# Should mutexes be stored in main or in the object?

Tags: c, thread-safety, mutex

Take this example of an object in C:

```
/* object.h */

typedef struct Object Object;

Object* createObject();
void freeObject(Object* object);

int getObjectNumber(Object* object);
void incrementObjectNumber(Object* object);
```

It is a very simple opaque type that stores a number and can increment it.

In order to make my code thread safe, I have two options. The first is to store a mutex within Object:

```
void
func(Object* object)
{
    incrementObject(object);
}

int
main()
{
    Object* object = createObject();

    Thread thread1 = startThread(func, object);
    Thread thread2 = startThread(func, object);

    waitThread(thread1);
    waitThread(thread2);

    freeObject(object);
}
```

The second is to store a mutex in main:

```
void
func(Object* object, Mutex mutex)
{
    lockMutex(mutex);
    incrementObject(object);
    unlockMutex(mutex);
}

int
main()
{
    Object* object = createObject();

    Mutex mutex;

    Thread thread1 = startThread(func, object, mutex);
    Thread thread2 = startThread(func, object, mutex);

    waitThread(thread1);
    waitThread(thread2);

    freeObject(object);
}
```

Which one is better practice, if there will only ever be one Object?

Comment: It's common practice to store mutexes in the objects they protect.

(In your code, I'd worry more about Object* createObject();, which should be Object *createObject(void); and the lack of (any indications that you at least intend to do) any error checking.)

Comment: @PSkocik why should it matter if you define void or not, it is redundant?

Comment: It's not redundant in C (only in C++). `int foo();` means `foo` takes an unspecified number of promoted args. It's a prototypeless, deprecated function declaration style. `int foo(void);` means foo takes no args. The two are differently typechecked (the first very weakly, which is why it's dangerous) and a call to the first (unrecommended) `foo();` might (will on x86_64 SysV ABI, by 1 extra instruction) generate bloatier calls in assembly.

Comment: @PSkocik Thanks, I didn't know that, I'll use void in my empty function calls from now on. This is not real code, its just a demonstration, and that's why there isn't any error checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. Sometimes you want interior thread safety, sometimes exterior.

Typically, the decision will depend on whether an external user needs to compose operations or not. Say, they want both `f()` and `g()` to happen atomically. If you hide the mutex inside `Object`, there is no way they can achieve that without managing another mutex themselves (and then you have to deal with several locks being used, which can lead to deadlocks, etc.).

Comment: Yeah...the way round that is to provide lock() and unlock() functions that can be used to extend the lock span, if required.  It helps if you have a reentrant mutex with a lock count:)

Answer (score 5):

No matter if there is one object or several, it is a good idea to store the mutex together with the opaque object. First of all, the mutex and the data it protects belong together. But also, thread-safety needs to be dealt with by your "ADT" and not by the caller. Access to objects should only occur through setters/getters, which will handle thread-safety internally. In this case `incrementObject`.

That way you may declare that your whole library is thread-safe, it takes care of itself rather than dumping the responsibility on someone else. Your 1st example has a much cleaner API, while the 2nd one requires the caller to drag around a mutex into their user-defined callback, which isn't a clean solution.